# iOS App crashed if I installed googleApis with latest version of Firbase through cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

In my app I have been trying installing latest version of Firebase crashlytics and Analytics pod file and it works fine as well. But the problem occurs when I also installed googleapis pod file (ie. used for speech recognition) with latest version of Firbase crashlytics and Analytics pod file it just crashed the app while launching the app. And the problem is I cannot degrade the Firbase version as it is going to deprecate soon.

Example:-

if installed only below two it worked fine

`pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'`
`pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`

Crash occurs, if installed below googleapis pod file with Firbase pod files:-

`pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'`
`pod 'Firebase/Analytics'`
`pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'`

Error:-

`<ERROR> Flag decoder failed: missing required field`

`ProtocolBuffer message hasn't been initialized. SetString can't be performed`

`ProtocolBuffer message hasn't been initialized. SetInt64 can't be performed`

`7.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800002] Cannot register experiment client invalid flags.  Flag name, value: redundant_engagement_removal_enabled, 0`

Any suggestion, how I can resolve this crash?? As I want to use googleapis pod file including latest version of Firebase(Crashlytics and Analytics)

Comment: Did you configure firebase?

Comment: Yes, This line FirebaseApp.configure() is crashing the app. And when I remove this line then the app is working fine(obviously without firebase).

Comment: Please share Podfile and Podfile.lock.  Best guess is that you may need to add a minimum_ios version to the Podfile.